# Applescript (Adobe Illustrator) find coincident X coordinate on a path for any given Y coordinate

Tags: applescript, graphics, adobe, design

I have two lines as shown in the screenshot below (Adobe Illustrator file) which my script produces.

Is there any way, using AppleScript, to find the value of X for the coincident points on the curvy vertical lines for any given value of Y?  For example if I wanted to add horizontal lines between the two vertical paths at the points indicated on the screenshot...

EDIT: I'm guessing that this is not going to be a built in function of AppleScript / Illustrator but I'm also guessing there must be a way to map a point on the path from the information used to build the path... ie the previous and next anchor points and the positions of the handles...

Could anyone explain how this works?  What the formula might be?

[image]

Comment: As a tool I have found useful in the past to convert any graph to a set of x & y values, have a look for DataThief...

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for that... never heard of it before but I've made a note.  Very interesting.

Comment: @SolarMike In this case i need the function to be incorporated in the script.  My script produces these paths but i really need to be able to add points to the paths after they are computed.  I've got all the data that makes the path (anchors, handles etc...) I just can't figure out how to use that information to plot a point on the path for a given value of Y.

Comment: [This PDF on curve-fitting techniques](https://legacy.essie.ufl.edu/~kgurl/Classes/Lect3421/Spring_01/NM6_curve_s01.pdf) might be helpful, and gives you an idea of the approach.  I think it'll be slightly simpler in your case, as you're only focussing on a single point of intersection and the small area around that point where you'll be using existing data values to hone in closer and closer to the true value.  But it's still going to take some grit.